# Docker container hanging on docker stop (Windows Container)

Tags: docker, containers

I have a container that I want to stop, but when I do a `docker stop [CONTAINER_ID]` it hangs and never stops it.

I have tried the normal `docker stop` and `docker ps -q | % { docker stop $_ }`

Comment: can you give us MVP?

Comment: have you tried to kill the container?

Comment: @AmitBaranes Yes I just tried and no good.

Comment: @golobich What is that?

Comment: @Cameron any logs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you may give it a try for  `docker system prune`, but carefull it removes all unused ones

Comment: @AmitBaranes I did docker logs [Container] and I got "Error response from daemon: can not get logs from container which is dead or marked for removal" which I guess it somehow became dead?

Comment: take a look at this talk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794108/docker-cannot-remove-dead-container, Let me know if you still have this issue afterward

Comment: @AmitBaranes I was reading that, but I am using Windows containers.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this previously.

Stop the docker daemon, whether its in services (enterprise) or in the icon tray (normal) and restart the daemon, this should free up the resources so you can properly remove it using `docker stop ID` and `docker rm ID`