# docker : removal of container takes too long

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I want to remove a container, the removal takes too long

```
sudo docker rm -f container_name
```

When I re-ran the command I got:

```
Error response from daemon: removal of container container_name is already in progress
```

The environment I am using:

- Docker version: 17.05.0-ce
- Ubuntu version: 16.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker - Cannot remove dead container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794108/docker-cannot-remove-dead-container)

Comment: please, share the command you use to remove the container. inspecting the logs of the container may help too

Comment: @rok I already shared it, sudo docker rm -f container_name

Comment: Did you tried `docker system prune` after stopping that container?

Comment: I just reloved the issue, look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after restarting docker daemon, I can remove the container.

`sudo service docker restart`

`sudo docker rm -f container_name`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24546810)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24546810)

Comment: @shyam if my answer lacks additional information, please refer to what kind of infos

Comment: @WillieCheng docker daemon stucks, so it cannot remove the container, this answer resolved the issue for me